# Edge detection with Single-Pass Wireframe Rendering

Tags: opengl, edge-detection

I would like to implement a typical CAD software and therefore need an edge detection algorithm to draw the silhouette of various meshes. Silhouette includes outline, ridges and creases of various objects. Here is an example of a cube created in Blender where the silhouette is made of thick orange lines:

[image]

I want to use a geometrical approach where wireframes are drawn on top of the objects and interior lines like diagonals are omitted. The wireframe rendering is described [here](http://strattonbrazil.blogspot.co.at/2011/09/single-pass-wireframe-rendering_10.html). In this article, the geometry shader is used to draw the wireframe. 
It is also explained that one has to set a per-vertex attribute to decide if a line should be omitted or not.

My question is: How could I decide which lines I have to omit? I use OpenGL as rendering API by the way.

EDIT: To clarify, I really want to draw just the edges that constitutes the silhouette but not any diagonals. Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: "*Silhouette includes outline, ridges and creases of various objects.*" That's not [what "silhouette" means](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/silhouette).

Comment: Taking into account what Nicol Bolas said, which is true, I think what you're looking for is the following: an edge should only be visible if the normals of the two triangles connected to the edge are NOT the same. Is that true? Because that can be calculated very easily via a dot product, provided you have the 2 connected triangle normals. Now this is where your discription becomes vague, so you might need to consider a fuzzy threshold in normal difference when deciding to show a line, to allow spheres and curves to be "edge-less" as well.

Comment: Jep that assumption is correct TWT. So do you know if it is possible to compare triangle normals in the geometry shader? Or would I have to pre-process the triangles and mark all edges that have the same normal direction and consequently shouldn't be rendered?

Comment: Either could work, and I guess pre-marking on the cpu would be fast enough for a cad program. Doing it in the geo shader is much more elegant though, but also much more difficult. I can't help you with that, unfortunately, since I don't know much about them. I don't think its very easy to procure adjacency data in the geo shader, which could be a major hurdle. It should be a common enough problem though, just google around a little. Also, when you reply to a comment try referencing the user, otherwise they don't get a notification. Good luck.

Comment: I'll have a try, thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample pictures I infer that you want to enhance

- the silhouette edges, i.e. those that belong to the outline of the projections,
- the salient edges, i.e. those that join two angled faces.

The former are determined by looking at the orientation of the faces: a face is "facing" when the observer is outside the half-space it delimits and conversely. A silhouette edge is one that belongs to a facing face and a non-facing face. Note that this is a viewer-dependent property.

A salient edge is such that it joins two faces forming a sufficiently large angle that the connection is considered non-smooth. (The angle threshold is up to you.) This is a viewer-independent property.

Comment: That is correct. I'm not sure how to determine silhouette edges, i.e. how to detect if an edge belongs to a facing face and a none-facing face. I'll google for this. Thank you!

Comment: @enne87 Establish the equation of the plane of the face with an outward-pointing normal and plug the coordinates of the observer. Would be nice to insert a result in your answer if you succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider freestyle
https://www.blender.org/manual/en/render/freestyle/index.html

> Freestyle is an edge- and line-based non-photorealistic (NPR) rendering >engine. It relies on mesh data and z-depth information to draw lines on >selected edge types. Various line styles can be added to produce >artistic (“hand drawn”, “painted”, etc.) or technical (hard line) looks.

I haven't used it yet, but am planning to give it a try for creating line drawings from 3d models.

Comment: Thanks but how could I use that to implement my own edge detection shader?